# How do I install the Telarus GeoQuote Plugin to my WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, installation

I have a plugin from Telarus called GeoQuote. It's a lead generation plugin for their agents, and I'm trying to help an agent get the plugin working on his WordPress site. I have all the php files and the css file in a separate folder.

My question is, how do I get it on the website now? I tried the WordPress plugin installer, but it didn't work.

I'm assuming I can upload the files to the hosting server with FTP and then use php code to call on the plugin in the widget area I created in WordPress. But I don't know what kind of code to use.

Can someone help walk me through this or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably start with asking Telarus.

Comment: I did. They sent me to a YouTube video that briefly says their plugin can work with WordPress, and then the video moves on to other subjects with no further explanation..